# Make a form from models using ModelForm, Models have many Foreignkeys( one class is the foreign key for the other.)

Tags: python, django, forms

I wanted to make a form which should be showing all the fields defined in models, wether the fields include a foreign key to some other class in the models. I am using ModelForm to generate forms.

My models look like

```
class Employee(Person):
   nickname = models.CharField(_('nickname'), max_length=25, null=True,
     blank=True)
   blood_type = models.CharField(_('blood group'), max_length=3, null=True,
     blank=True, choices=BLOOD_TYPE_CHOICES)
   marital_status = models.CharField(_('marital status'), max_length=1,
     null=True, blank=True, choices=MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES)
   nationality = CountryField(_('nationality'), default='IN', null=True,
     blank=True)
   about = models.TextField(_('about'), blank=True, null=True)

   dependent = models.ManyToManyField(Dependent,
     through='DependentRelationship')

   pan_card_number = models.CharField(_('PAN card number'), max_length=50,
     blank=True, null=True)
   policy_number = models.CharField(_('policy number'), max_length=50,
     null=True, blank=True)

   # code specific details
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True,
     verbose_name=_('user'))
   date_added = models.DateTimeField(_('date added'), auto_now_add=True)
   date_modified = models.DateTimeField(_('last modified'), auto_now=True)

   @models.permalink
   def get_absolute_url(self):
     return ('contacts_employee_detail', [str(self.id)])

class Person(models.Model):
  """Person model"""

  title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
  first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=100)
  middle_name = models.CharField(_('middle name'), max_length=100, null=True,
      blank=True)
  last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=100, null=True,
      blank=True)
  suffix = models.CharField(_('suffix'), max_length=20, null=True,
      blank=True)

  slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'), max_length=50, unique=True)

  phone_number = generic.GenericRelation('PhoneNumber')
  email_address = generic.GenericRelation('EmailAddress')
  address = generic.GenericRelation('Address')

  date_of_birth = models.DateField(_('date of birth'), null=True, blank=True)
  gender = models.CharField(_('gender'), max_length=1, null=True,
     blank=True, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)

class Address(models.Model):
 """Street Address model"""

  TYPE_CHOICES = (
     ('c', _('correspondence address')),
     ('p', _('present address')),
     ('m', _('permanent address')),
  )

  address_type = models.CharField(_('address type'), max_length=1,
    choices=TYPE_CHOICES)

  content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
     limit_choices_to={'app_label': 'contacts'})
  object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()

  street = models.TextField(_('street'), blank=True, null=True)
  city = models.CharField(_('city'), max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
  province = models.CharField(_('State/UT'), max_length=200, blank=True,
     null=True)
  post_code = models.CharField(_('postal code'), max_length=15, blank=True,
     null=True)
  country = CountryField(_('country'), default='IN')

  date_added = models.DateTimeField(_('date added'), auto_now_add=True)
  date_modified = models.DateTimeField(_('date modified'), auto_now=True)
```

So please if anyone could help me out, or suggest me some useful links from where i can get some help. Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)...

Basic usage is:

```
class EmployeeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('somefield','otherfield')
```

etc...

fields is a optional argument, used for defining witch fields will be presented on the form... You can also override some fields using the following

```
class EmployeeForm(ModelForm):
    otherfield = forms.CharField(...)
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('somefield','otherfield')
```

That means, Your form is created from Employee model, "somefield" and "otherfield" will be added as form fields, and somefield will be populated directly from your model, but otherfield will be defined as if you override it in the form class...

EDIT: Overriding is used for small changes, so ,it is not right to change the data type of the field... As far as you gave the field same name, there is no problem, it will match the related model field using the name of the form field... So:

```
class SomeModel(Model):
    somefield = CharField()

class SomeForm(ModelForm):
    somefield = Charfield(Widget=...)
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
```

Since field names are equivalent, there is no problem...
Basic reason for overriding is, you may wish to use a widget to change the appearance of the form field(making a TextField looks like a single line Charfield) or pass some attributes (like defining cols and rows of a text field, or addng a simlpe datepicker to a datetime field. Or you may wish to use choices parameter to populate a field with **value-label** pairs...

You must aviod any kind of data-based changes, if you do, you might get a database level error.

Comment: but wether its the correct way to do this thing, bcoz overriding the field is possible but the value of that field is to be stored somewhere in the database, and if I override the fields is it going to go in the actual place in the database.